# Why do we have to set __block variable to nil?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

From the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW11)

> Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles
>
> You can use lifetime qualifiers to avoid strong reference cycles. For
>   example, typically if you have a graph of objects arranged in a
>   parent-child hierarchy and parents need to refer to their children and
>   vice versa, then you make the parent-to-child relationship strong and
>   the child-to-parent relationship weak. Other situations may be more
>   subtle, particularly when they involve block objects.
>
> In manual reference counting mode, `__block id x;` has the effect of not
>   retaining `x`. In ARC mode, `__block id x;` defaults to retaining `x` (just
>   like all other values). To get the manual reference counting mode
>   behavior under ARC, you could use `__unsafe_unretained __block id x;`.
>   As the name `__unsafe_unretained` implies, however, having a
>   non-retained variable is dangerous (because it can dangle) and is
>   therefore discouraged. Two better options are to either use `__weak` (if
>   you don’t need to support iOS 4 or OS X v10.6), or set the `__block`
>   value to `nil` to break the retain cycle.

Okay, so what's different about `__block` variable?

Why set to `nil` here? Is `__block` variable retained twice? Who hold all the reference? The block? The heap? The stack? The thread? The what?

The following code fragment illustrates this issue using a pattern that is sometimes used in manual reference counting.

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init…];

// ...

myController.completionHandler =  ^(NSInteger result) {
   [myController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};

[self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:^{
   [myController release];
}];
```

As described, instead, you can use a `__block` qualifier and set the myController variable to `nil` in the completion handler:

```
MyViewController * __block myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init…]; //Why use __block. my controller is not changed at all

// ...

myController.completionHandler =  ^(NSInteger result) {
    [myController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    myController = nil; //Why set to nil here? Is __block variable retained twice? Who hold all the reference? The block? The heap? The stack? The thread? The what?
};
```

Also why `myController` is not set to `nil` by compiler. Why do we have to do so? It seems that the compiler sort of know when myController will no longer be used again namely when the block expire.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you have code of this form:

```
object.block = ^{
    // reference object from inside the block
    [object someMethodOrProperty];
};
```

`object` will retain or copy the block you give to it. But the block itself will also retain `object` because it is strongly referenced from within the block. This is a retain cycle. Even after the block has finished executing, the reference cycle still exists and neither the object nor the block can be deallocated. Remember that a block can be called multiple times, so it cannot just forget all the variables it references after it has finished executing once.

To break this cycle, you can define `object` to be a `__block` variable, which allows you to change its value from inside the block, e.g. changing it to `nil` to break the cycle:

```
__block id object = ...;
object.block = ^{
    // reference object from inside the block
    [object someMethodOrProperty];

    object = nil;
    // At this point, the block no longer retains object, so the cycle is broken
};
```

When we assign `object` to `nil` at the end of the block, the block will no longer retain `object` and the retain cycle is broken. This allows both objects to be deallocated.

One concrete example of this is with with `NSOperation`'s `completionBlock` property. If you use the `completionBlock` to access an operation's result, you need to break the retain cycle that is created:

```
__block NSOperation *op = [self operationForProcessingSomeData];
op.completionBlock = ^{
    // since we strongly reference op here, a retain cycle is created
    [self operationFinishedWithData:op.processedData];

    // break the retain cycle!
    op = nil;
}
```

As the documentation describes, there are a number of other techniques you can also use to break these retain cycles. For example, you will need to use a different technique in non-ARC code than you would in ARC code.

Comment: "But the block itself will also retain object because it is strongly referenced from within the block." Why? Closure.

Comment: How does adding __block make any difference anyway?

Comment: When a block captures a pointer to an objective-c object, that object will be retained unless you use `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained` (or `__block` in non-ARC code).

Comment: In non-ARC code, `__block` variables are not retained. This was an implementation detail however, not the semantic meaning of `__block`. `__block` simply allows you to change the value of a variable from inside a block. In ARC code, `__block` variables are retained like non-`__block` variables. So we define the `object` variable as `__block` so we can set it to `nil` from inside the block and break the retain cycle. Brain hurt yet?

Comment: In your sample object.block = bla bla bla. That's not very common. Why would the object retain the block?

Comment: It's actually very common. `NSOperation *operation = ...; operation.completionBlock = ^{ // code to execute when the operation is finished, which often will try to access operation } `. That's just one example.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.rotationBlock = ^{
    typeof (weakSelf) __strong self = weakSelf;

    [self yourCodeThatReferenceSelf];
};
```

What happens is that the block will capture self as a *weak* reference and there will be no retain cycle. self inside the block is then redefined as __strong self = weakSelf before your code runs. This prevents self from being released while your block runs.